# How do I determine periodicity of a function through a system of functional equations?

Tags: functional-equations

I was given these equations,
$f(k+x) = f(k-x)$,
$f(2k+x)= -f(2k-x)$ .
k is assumed a constant.
I was asked to comment whether $f(x)$ is even or odd.
By solving I came to the equation,
$f(-x)=-f(x)$,which states that $f(x)$ is an odd function.
But how do I comment on its periodic nature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since an odd function(you have proved), implies$$ -f(2k-x)=f(x-2k)$$
So $$f(x-2k)=f(x+2k)$$
so period is $4k$.